# Image from static resource not working in formula

Tags: static-resources, image-formula

I have few images (Star01, Star02...etc) Which i clubbed to a Folder called StarsImg, Then i zipped this folder (Name of zipped File is same StarsImg). 
Now i have uploaded this zip file as Static resource called ImageFolder.

When i click on View File link of the static resource i get (https://c.ap5.visual.force.com/resource/1532103092000/ImageFolder)

So in formula i tried this address : "/resource/1532103092000/ImageFolder/StarsImg/StarsImg/Star01"

But its not working..What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to include the file extension (e.g. .jpg, .gif); the only time you don't do this is when you're referencing the static resource itself (e.g. `/resource/ImageFolder` represents the static resource, but `/resource/ImageFolder/StarsImg/Star01.gif` would represent a file in the ZIP). Second, make sure the folder path is correct, and observe the entire path as case-sensitive names. Depending on the context, consider using URLFOR, as in:  `{!URLFOR($Resource.ImageFolder,'/StarsImg/Star01.gif')}`. This is not available in all contexts, of course.